# How to call a class with arguments from an array within a function (PHP)?

Tags: php, function, class, variables, return

I am having several STD Classes, such as $orders, $customers and $invoices. Those classes contain a lot information. Perhaps it sounds unnecessary, but I'd like to uniform the information I need into some arrays (there might be better ways, but this helps me understanding the material).

So I made a function:

```
function createarray($input_array,$input_targets,$i)
{
    return $input_array->collection[0]->$input_targets[$i];
}
```

(Of course, the function does more than that)

I created an array, consisting of the same keys that are used in the class $orders.

```
$input_array=['number','date','amount'];
$result=createarray($orders,$input_array,0); //Should output the same as $orders->number
$result=createarray($orders,$input_array,1); //Should output the same as $orders->date
$result=createarray($orders,$input_array,2); //Should output the same as $orders->amount
```

But it seems that ->$ is not possible. How do I achieve my goal?

Comment: Not entirely sure I understand how this helps you, but anyway...  You could try $input_array->collection[0]->{$input_targets[$i]};  (ie, put curly brackets around the variable property name)

Comment: @RobEyre Well, it seems like you understood what I meant (sorry if I confused you), because it works. Funny enough: I already tried it, but it didn't work. Guess I made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: The way you wrote it in your question is parsed as `($input_array->collection[0]->$input_targets)[$i]`. It expects `$input_targets` to be the name of the property, and the value of the property to be an array.