# How to I call a class from a variable with curly brackets, if the class has layered keys?

Tags: php, class, variables, return, curly-braces

In addition to my previous question ([How to call a class with arguments from an array within a function (PHP)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75867727/how-to-call-a-class-with-arguments-from-an-array-within-a-function-php))

```
$testvar1="paymentTerms->daysOfCredit";
$testvar2="orderNumber";
echo $input_obj->collection[0]->paymentTerms->daysOfCredit; //returns 8
echo $input_obj->collection[0]->orderNumber; //returns 159
echo $input_obj->collection[0]->{$testvar1}; //Returns nothing, should return 8
echo $input_obj->collection[0]->{$testvar2}; //Returns 159
```

Something with explode and shorthand code? Or wouldn't that work?

Comment: I guess you could use $testVar1Bits = explode('->', $testVar1); and then ...->{$testVar1Bits[0]}->{$testVar1Bits[1]} ...  but this is really awkward.  Not sure what you're trying to accomplish here

Answer (score 1):

You need to split the string. Then you can loop over it to get each nested element.

```
$props = explode('->', $testvar1);
$obj = $input_obj->collection[0];
foreach ($props as $p) {
    $obj = $obj->$p;
}
var_dump($obj);
```

Comment: Thank you. I haven't tested yet, but I know this will work :) it is exactly what I need 

Comment: Tested at it works. Thanks